# How to prevent storage error in Angular SSR app guards and services (Angular V17)

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

In Angular V17 SSR app case, Is there an equivalent of afterNextRender that I could use in services or guards (functional guards or not) for prevent undefined localStorage/Sessionstorage error without using the old platformId.

Thanks

I tried

```
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';

 async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
if (!this._platform.isBrowser) 
   {
    //use Storage function
   }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Found an article that helped me with something similar. [Link](https://santibarbat.medium.com/how-to-use-localstorage-with-angular-9-universal-ssr-517578615637)

Answer (score 0):

ATM there is no alternative to using `PLATFORM_ID` and `isPlatformBrowser` when you're outside a component content.